# Shopify - Get list of product from a specific collection

Tags: shopify

In shopify, I am creating 4 dropdowns.

Dropdown 1 - City
Dropdown 2 - Category of shops (such as Apparel, stationary etc)
Dropdown 3 - Shops available in the particular city and particular shop
Dropdown 4 - Items available in the particular shop

My requirement is, when a particular shop is selected (Dropdown 3) below the dropdown all the products in that shop should be listed (I will make the product part of collection and collection name will be same as shop name).

I realize that I need to use Ajax. I checked the APIs offered by shopify but somehow I am not able to connect dots. I am not able to use it. Can you please provide a pointer where it is explained how to achieve it.

Please note, i am new to web development and shopify.

**EDITED***

1. I have created another template called "collection.alternate".
2. Tagged the collection to the new template.
3. In theme.liquid I have used the following code, to avoid header and footer from getting displayed in iframe

   {% if template != 'collection.alternate' %}
     {% include 'header-bar' %}
     .....
   {% endif %}
4. Used iframe to load the collection.alternate.

However in iframe the Header is still getting displayed. When I analyze the "Elements" in Chrome developer tools for the iframe, I see the header logic is generated for collection.template. How do I stop header from appearing in iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need AJAX for this functionality.

Each values in the four dropdowns should be added as tags in the products. Then you can use simple JavaScript command to change the url as required and display required products.

*For ex., let's say you have New York as a **City**, and CK as a **Shop**. Now to display the products that are in CK store in New York, all the said products must contain New York and CK as tags. The final URL to display the said products will be - **storename.myshopify.com/collections/all/new-york+ck***

Comment: Thanks @Hymnz, neat trick. I was not aware of that. As per your suggestion, after 4th drop down is selected, I need to redirect and open the collection page. However, rather than opening a page, I am interested in showing the products on the same page below the dropdown.

Comment: Use iframe. If you don't want to do that, then the client side load will be too heavy if the products count is too huge. Have a look at this - http://satterfield-pfeffer5655.myshopify.com/collections/all

Comment: after posting the earlier comment, I remembered iframe and I am using it. However iframe is showing up header and footer. I am trying to see if I can get rid of header and footer.

Comment: Add a different layout option without header/footer

Comment: in the shopify shop link that you posted, there are two dropdown, shop by category and shop by brand. I implemented the same, however when I am selecting the second drop down, the first one is getting reset. How do I disable that behavior.

Comment: @HymnZzy How can get the product selected collection on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

To call products from shopify collects you can simply use this loop:

```
{% for product in collections.shop_name.products limit: 4 %}     /*********** shop_name is collections name limit is used to show no. of products ******/
       <li><a href="{{ product.url}}"><img src="{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'medium' }}" alt=""></a></li>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks @Yatin, however my requirement is to get the list of product after user selects the shop name. Where do I put the snippet you have provided and how do I invoke it...

Comment: when you click on the shop name it will open a new page and use above code in that page

Answer (score 0):

Below is the link to shopify article that describes how to filter products based on tags.

https://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/collections/filtering-a-collection-with-multiple-tag-drop-down

Thanks @Hymnz for guiding me to the article.

Answer (score 0):

Just mention your collection name in collection array index

```
{% for product in collections['collection-name'].products %}
{{product.name}}
{% endfor %}
```